# Why IP of nslookup and ping is not the same

Tags: windows, networking, cmd

I have a question I try to do a ping in the cmd like this: ping google.com, so it gives me an IP address A. But after, I want to do an nslookup to google.com It gives me an IP address B. Why ? My question is why the IP are not the same from the same website.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is probably round-robin DNS.  DNS allow you to specify multiple values for the same record, and the client library will determine with one to use (some use the first, some use the last, some use a random one, and some iterate through them).

Alternatively, the DNS server may be returning different values to the same query - either to do load balancing behind the scenes, or to send you to the geographically closest server.

I just resolved google.com from two separate computers and got two different answers: 
host-a5$ dig +short google.com
216.58.204.14

host-b4$ dig +short google.com
172.217.23.14

This shows that the google DNS servers are returning different answers for the same query, most likely for load balancing and/or geo-centric reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 3 reasons:

- ping might be getting an address from hosts file (nslookup doesn't)
- ping might be getting a cached address  (nslookup doesn't). Use `ipconfig /flushdns` to empty the cache.
- the same host may have more than one addresses registered in the DNS